# Mysql query is not working property

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP, it's learning process. Now I'm getting tired to fix this issue. I've a mysql database where a few row exits. Like :

```
1) pro_no_sleep  2) pro_country 3) pro_state 4) pro_city etc..
```

When i run a query to get this database content, it's doesn't show duplicate value content. for example. In my **pro_no_sleep** row 2 value are same: Like **1**

```
pro_no_sleep
1
1
2
3
```

So when i run following query with php it's doesn't show duplication value content. It's show only unique value content. Like 2 and 3.

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step1 WHERE pro_no_sleep = '$people' OR 
pro_country = '$country' OR pro_state = '$region' OR pro_city = '$destination'");
```

I didn't use **%** sign in my query because of html form table has fix value from select tag.

Php Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['Submit']) && $_GET['Submit'] == "Search") {
    require_once("func.php");
    $people      = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['people'])));
    $country     = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['country'])));
    $region      = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['region-depart'])));
    $destination = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['destination'])));
    $from        = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['from'])));
    $to          = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['to'])));
    $upload      = "user/content/uploaded";


    $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step1 WHERE pro_no_sleep = '$people' OR pro_country = '$country' OR pro_state = '$region' OR pro_city = '$destination'");

    $num = mysql_num_rows($search);

    if ($num == 1) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $num . " result found.";
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
            echo "<div id='rightsearch'>";
            $propertyid     = (int) $result['propertyid'];
            $getimg         = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step3 WHERE propertyid = 
            '$propertyid' ORDER BY imgname LIMIT 1");
            $protitle_d     = $result['pro_title'];
            $country_d      = $result['pro_country'];
            $region_d       = $result['pro_state'];
            $destination_d  = $result['pro_city'];
            $pro_des_d      = $result['pro_des'];
            $pro_type_d     = $result['pro_type'];
            $pro_no_bed_d   = $result['pro_no_bed'];
            $pro_no_bath_d  = $result['pro_no_bath'];
            $pro_no_sleep_d = $result['pro_no_sleep'];
            $getreview      = mysql_query("SELECT rating FROM property_review WHERE p_id = '$propertyid'");
            $num_review     = mysql_num_rows($getreview);


            while ($reimg = mysql_fetch_array($getimg)) {
                $img = $reimg['imgname'];
                echo "<a href='details.php?propertyid=$propertyid'>";
                echo '<img src="' . $upload . '/' . $img . '" width="' . 100 . '" height=" ' . 100 . '"  />';
                echo "</a>";
            }

            echo "<h2>$protitle_d</h2>";
            echo "<p>$country_d, $region_d, $destination_d</p>";
            //echo myTruncate($pro_des_d, 100) . "<br/>";                       
            echo $pro_des_d . "<br/>";
            echo "<h5>$pro_type_d, $pro_no_bed_d bedroom";
            if ($pro_no_bed_d > 1) {
                echo $plural = "s";
            }
            echo ",";
            echo " $pro_no_bath_d bath";
            if ($pro_no_bath_d > 1) {
                echo $plural2 = "s";
            }
            echo ",";
            echo " $pro_no_sleep_d sleep";
            if ($pro_no_sleep_d > 1) {
                echo $plural3 = "s";
            }
            echo "</h5>";
            echo "$num_review review";
            echo "</div>";
        } // first while statement
    } // second if statment
    else {
        echo "<div id='rightsearch'>";
        echo "No result found";
        echo "</div>";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: how are you iterating over the query result to display the data? Did you run the query in a something like phpMyAdmin or another MySQL client and see the results there?

Comment: yes i did it. it's doesn't show duplication value.

Comment: I think it's my query issue.. i don't know.

Comment: Update the question with the final query that the PHP executes (substituting the variables with their values)... you can do an `echo "SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($search);

    if ($num == 1) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $num . " result found.";
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
...
```

`mysql_num_rows` returns the number of rows in the result. So you check if the result contains only one row, iterate over all the rows (remember, there's only one!) and do something.

What you need to do is check if the result contains *at least* one row.

```
if ($num >= 1) {
```